# UITableView Scroll Lags with Parse Images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I've seen several other threads on this, but none using Parse. We have 3 things going on. First, the TableView that lags when it scrolls. Second, the custom cell with the images and labels. And finally, the ParsePull class that fetches the data. We made a separate class for this to use it for other ViewControllers.

I'm pretty sure the problem is fetching each image every time the cell appears on the screen, but I don't know how to fix it. Below is the related code for each one.

UITableView with the following method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.eventData.count) {
        ParallaxEventCell *loadCell = (ParallaxEventCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"loadingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return loadCell; 
    } else{
        ParallaxEventCell *cell = (ParallaxEventCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"eventCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            //load an event cell
            [cell setUpEvent:[self.eventData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

            return cell;    
    }
}
```

ParallaxEventCell:

```
-(void)setUpEvent:(id)event{

    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.titleLabel.text = [event objectForKey:@"eventTitle"];
    self.venueNameLabel.text = [event objectForKey:@"eventVenue"];
    self.priceLabel.text = [event objectForKey:@"eventPrice"];
    self.customDateLabel.text = [self dateStringFromDate:[event objectForKey:@"eventDate"]];
    self.eventURL = [event objectForKey:@"urlString"];
    self.geoPoint = [event objectForKey:@"GeoPoint"];
    self.descriptionText = [event objectForKey:@"eventDescription"];


    [ParsePull picturefromFile:[event objectForKey:@"eventImage"] withCompletion:^(UIImage *returnedImage) {
        self.customImageView.clipsToBounds = NO;
        self.customImageView.image = returnedImage;
        NSLog(@"setUpEvent");
    }];
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    // Store image
    self.customImageView.image = image;

    // Update padding
    [self setImageOffset:self.imageOffset];
}
```

ParsePull

```
+(void)picturefromFile:(PFFile *)file withCompletion:(PictureBlock)logo{
    NSLog(@"pictureFromFile");
    [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
             logo([UIImage imageWithData:data]);
                    }
        else{
        logo(nil);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Does it drop frames continuously or just jump when a cell is about to come on screen?

Comment: It jumps to the next cell a bit.